# How do you draw a condensed molecular structure with multiple side chains?

Tags: chemfig, mhchem, chemmacros

So I am trying to draw the molecule in the picture, but when I tried, it made weird spaces in between the parts not in `chemfig`. How can I do it entirely on `chemfig`?

[image]

MWE:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Example:
$\ce{CH3CH2}\chemfig{CH(-[6]CH_3)}\ce{CH2}$\chemfig{C-[6]CH3}HCH2\chemfig{C=[2]O}H

Attempt:
\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CH(-[6,,5]CH_3)CH_2CHCH_2CH-[6,,9]CH_3=O}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chemfig{CH_3CH_2CHCH_2CHCH_2CH(-[6,,5]CH_3)(-[6,,9]CH_3)(=[2,,13]O)}`

Comment: @polyn Thank you!!